are there two sorts of classical musicians?
recently, i’ve had a conversation with a classical musician, in which he reluctantly admitted that in his view there are really two clearly divided sorts of classical musicians; he explained it something like this (with more of my words than his):

there are, on the one side, classical musicians who “just get it” and play with life, vigor and vision; they are rather artists than musicians at their instrument and bring meaning to their music. they usually play at a very high technical level, but it is not essential to their playing, just necessary for what they actually do. they are very few, but whenever two of them meet, they recognize each other and sense a kinship of soul, and they all agree about who else is “in” and who isn’t.

on the other side, there are classical musicians who may play extremely well (and not only with great virtuosity, but also with passion and sensitivity), win prizes, are highly regarded in the musical world and perhaps even world-renowned, really big names, but still lack that special something and, apparently, are oblivious to it. they are not artists, but just musicians. they bring nothing else to their music but music. they may be great at that, but they are not more. no matter with how much emotion they play, their music still sounds stale.


to him, the distinction is practically clear-cut. he can tell from the “first note” if a practising musician has it or not. he can tell from the “first lesson” if a beginning student has the potential for it or not. “getting it” is not learnable. it almost never happens that a musician transforms from “not having it” to “having it”. if it does, the reasons for it are magical or tragical. there are almost no musicians who are inbetween. it’s almost as if you are either born with it or not.
one may be tempted to write off such an expression as just a matter of taste of someone who’s maybe a bit conceited. but this classical musician is very humble and has been very uncomfortable in expressing these views; it seemed to me that he’d rather have different views and preferred if the world was different in that regard and he’s befriended with many classical musicians who don’t “get it” and he avoids talking to them about that. i've also since spoken to two other classical musicians and they confirmed what he said. furthermore, i’ve witnessed this sort of secret consensus myself when i independently talked to these two other classical musicians after a certain concert where they came to the same disappointed judgment about a certain performance of someone who, however, was regarded rather well by (seemingly) everyone else; they even described it in similar terms. this is what even lead me to bring up the topic. all this makes me think that perhaps, there is something “objective” to it, something more than mere personal preferences.

now this is my question: has a phenomenon such like this ever been researched or documented in any way? that apparently there are classical musicians who feel like this and agree with each other about who “gets it” and who doesn’t? to me, this seems like sort of a big deal, but searching the internet for it, i’ve found almost nothing - just here and there some individual comments expressing similiar views. so … what’s up with that?

An interesting slant on musos! It sort of follows the concept around those who play jazz well, and those who quite simply try, but can't. There are several instances of this phenomenon. The same would go for orators. I guess we know it exists, but probably it's not labelled.

Music is a highly collaborative art form and judging other music professionals like this risks relationships that are important for both artistic and commercial success.

There are two kinds of people in this world: those who think that large and diverse communities can be insightfully analyzed simply by sorting them into two monolithic subgroups on the basis of a highly abstract binary distinction… and those who don't. ;-)

More seriously: 1) please read about the topics that are covered here and how to keep questions and answers factually and objectively focused. There are a few problems with this question: it hinges on a distinction that is highly subjective; the most meaningful answers would be "opinion-based"; and questions like "is there any research on this subject" are off-topic because answers would be mostly "list-like" and simply point to external resources rather than answering the question right here.

(But seriously, no, there won't have been research on who "has it" and who doesn't; how would one even begin to approach that scientifically? But there is meaningful discussion to be had on this point, and I've sometimes thought similar things myself. I invite you to bring it up in the chat channel which is more suited for back-and-forth discussion.

@AndyBonner "how would one even begin to approach that scientifically" - aren't humanistic sciences full of research problems like that? I think it would make for a good subject that might even generate a lot of media attention i.e. money for the researchers. ;) Add "Artificial Intelligence" or some other buzzword for a jackpot.

@AndyBonner thanks, i will maybe come back to that invitation. it doesn’t have to be that scientific, just methodical. you could survey people who agree with this notion, interview them, let them sort a few dozen of well-known musicians (without reporting who is sorted in which category to not cause uproar) or have them listen to a predefined set of classical pieces and give their judgment to see how strong the agreement is. you could have them try to describe the difference and ask them whether they think it’s innate or not and so forth …

@AndyBonner or, perhaps most interestingly, you could have them meet up and listen to each other play among some “decoys” (who are musicians who think such a binary is bullshit) and afterwards have the binary-thinking musicians sort each other and the decoys anonymously and see if they got it right …

@AndyBonner finally, if there were, for instance, some autobiographies of well-known musicians who report this phenomenon and describe it like that, that would be also an instance of it being documented as asked for.

@piiperiReinstateMonica I could imagine as sociological survey of this notion, rather than of the phenomenon it purports to detect. My point is, the researcher certainly isn't in the business of identifying "who has it." Btw, windfish, I didn't mention it before, but such a concept isn't limited to classical music. Think of terms like "X factor" "star power." But one big problem with discussing even the notion is that most such terms are similarly vague. The people who use them, when pressed to define the parameters, might either differ or just shrug and say "je ne sais quoi."

@AndyBonner ella, elle l’a …

"they are not artists, but just musicians". I'd stop a while and consider how stupid, useless and arrogant is to make this arbitrary, completely subjective distinction. Then I'd consider how stupid and useless is to make such generic distinctions in the first place, no matter the field. And how pointless is to waste time finding argumentations about this, especially if trying to describe a whole "binary categorization" that should arbitrarily define anyone, in absolute ways. We may casually chat about that, but whenever I listen to such "arguments", my first thought is "that's just cr*p".

@windfish autobiographies would still be subjective, so they'd just be personal arguments based on biased experiences, not proper scientific research. And there couldn't be a proper scientific research about this that wouldn't consider its results as not absolute. Many factors may affect the outcome of a person as "successful artist" (whatever it could mean), including "sheer dumb luck" that could even change the career of an individual at different stages of their age or maturation. As with any categorization, it only makes sense in the context in which it's used, it doesn't define anybody.

@musicamante hey, i hope that my question didn’t offend you. as i said, the guy i’ve spoken to was not arrogant at all – this phrase came from one of the other two –, yet made the same distinction. the entire point of this question is to find out something about the people who distinguish in this way with the hope of examining whether such distinctions are indeed arbitrary or not or whether they are stable in some way. the point is not about whether such a distinction is subjective, but whether there is an objective reality behind it.

@musicamante and the distinction itself is not about being successful or not. in fact, i tried to make sure that being successful has nothing to do with it, by explicitly listing various criteria of success as irrelevant to what is meant. finally, i think you miss the point of the distinction not being made in deliberation as a useless intellectual exercise. the people i’ve been talking to just experience it, they observe that there are two sorts of musicians and they can’t help but see it that way. it’s what they hear.

@musicamante by analogy, imagine a world where most people couldn’t distinguish between green and blue. they wouldn’t be able to tell these colors apart or perhaps only if they were put next to each other. but then there would be some who could and not only tell them apart but immediately judge whether something’s green or blue. there’s perhaps some fuzzy line between these colors, but “inbetween instances” rarely occur in the natural world. to these few people, the distinction between blue and green would be anything but arbitrary whereas to most people it would be, as they simply can’t see.

@musicamante yet clearly, to be aware of such a distinction and the fact that some people could distinguish in this way would be very interesting. even if a researcher in this world cannot himself distinguish between green and blue, he could still setup experiments to see if those who claim they can, actually could.

@windfish Don't worry, no offense taken :-) It's just that I've listened to such arguments for so much time to realize how much they're irrelevant and inaccurate, especially when somebody claims that they can recognize them "from the first note". Yes, it's true that experienced musicians can recognize some level of awareness (let's call it "artistry", but it's quite subjective), and dividing into 2 distinct categories makes superficial discussion simpler. But, as said, that's just a generalization, and it must be considered as such. We may agree, to some level, that white and black »

@windfish » are relevant distinctions, but the grey areas between them is highly subjective. It's interesting that you use the color blindness analogy, as in reality, there are many levels of it: depending on the classifications, some may have different perceptions of the same color. And we're talking about scientific facts. What your friend proposes is a completely subjective argument (for which, yes, some level of success does affect it, as it may affect success to some level). I'm not saying your friend was arrogant, but that the opinion is (no matter how sincere and benevolent it »

@windfish » may have been). There are too many aspects that may affect the "musicianship" or "artistry" of an individual (at any level), but saying that one could just be "type A" or "type B" is exactly like saying that "if you're not an accomplished musician in your mid 20s, then you'll never be". Which is just bullsh*t as it would be for an "accomplished human being" concept. Yet, the point remains: what would be the practical use of making such a distinction? Is it accurate? Does it help in any way? No, it's not "interesting", as it's inaccurate, subjective, and, therefore, irrelevant.

I've left a comment in the chat room.

Long comment: I’m not sure if the question fits here to be honest. It appears to be a request for resources about something that should be quite opinion based. Because this is by no means a thing of classical musicians, but generally a thing with any kind of art. There are many ways to define what makes a good musician, and different people will have different ideas on this. And especially things like musicality are very fuzzy terms. Some people will say this musicians plays with so much musicality, and some will say this musician has no musicality, he cannot even keep his time.
What is true is that music — particularly classical music — offers many degrees of freedom and expression. This means great artists are able to really make great things. On the other hand especially the world of soloists is extremely competitive. This means that you do get artist who survive by technical brilliance. And for some people these are musicians with a lot of skill but little musicality.
But in then music has from the beginning been something that needs to be sold to people in some sense. In music you are dependent on other people liking what you do, and being willing to pay you for it. And thus we see certain type of musicians because there is at least some demand for it. You get musicians who play with a lot of pathos and “soul”, because there are people who like that thing. There are musicians who play with insane technique because there are people who like that thing. And thus both are fine.
There is of course a thing that due to the competitiveness of the business many musicians are trained for technical brilliance, and it is harder to survive as musicians if you do not have that level of technique. But mostly I think this is simply people liking different things, and expressing their own opinion of what makes musicality.
The important thing here is to be able to say: “I do not like the way X is playing Y” without projecting it on the person: “I to not like X, because he does not play Y well”.

thanks for your comment. just a little clarification on a subtlety in case this has been misunderstood: i don't ask for a resource on the distinction itself, but rather on the distinguishing, meaning the phenomenon that people do distinguish in this way; so … not a resource about “who gets it and who doesn’t” (which is subjective), but instead about “who distinguishes and who doesn’t” (which is objective). but of course, as you can imagine and already have assumed, i would also be interested in resources of the former type …

I wouldn’t say there are two types of musician.   Two levels of performance perhaps - or just a continual scale within which a musician sometimes reaches a summit.   And some musicians seem to find those summits more regularly than others!   But it’s all very subjective.

Quick answer before this gets closed. I have met this idea and I think it is an actual phenomenon that some musicians can relate to, and not only in the classical scene. It's not talked about a lot, because it can harm social relationships. The main point is, some musicians can convey feelings of their own with their instruments, but others merely perform given instructions, trying to superficially mimic feelings.

thanks! how come that only some can hear that while most people seemingly cannot?

@windfish The thing with good compositions is, even a complete amateur can mechanically perform them and it's going to be somewhat enjoyable. Even a machine can perform them, and most people will be able to enjoy the music. Even with horrible beep beep sounds, if it's a good melody, it's a good melody. The better the song, the more difficult it is to completely ruin it with any kind of incompetence or even deliberate butchery.

@piiperiReinstateMonica - I have listened to music where the timbre destroyed my ability to enjoy the piece compared to the solo piano version (e.g. Kirby Mass Attack's Skull Gang and Necrodeus themes).

@Dekkadeci It's a non-discrete phenomenon - if you study the whole population statistically, I'm sure you'll find that some percentage of people do tolerate it. ;)

“It's not talked about a lot, because it can harm social relationships.” Not all thoughts have to be talked about to be known by others. Merely thinking this way has seemed to me to be detrimental to successful relationships, because it’s pretty much impossible for such thoughts to have zero impact on your choices and actions, even if they are never articulated in words.

@windfish We can’t be certain that some people hear it and some don’t until we eliminate the possibility that everyone hears the difference and some don’t care about the difference. Personally I learned to enjoy Fur Elise when I’d only heard it played as an alarm tone on a digital watch in the 1980s, where it was merely a series of beeps of only one note at a time and completely rigid timing. The worst possible MIDI version you can imagine, but it was the only version I’d ever heard for several years before I found it was a “real” piece. I loved it even though it was just beeps.

@ToddWilcox Exactly! The melody is so strong, it takes skill and effort to ruin it. I'd say the composer was one of those who "got it". ;)
